# How can I have a user search a character array for a letter?

Tags: java, arrays

gets a single letter from the user. This method validates that it’s either a valid letter or the quit character, ‘!’. It'll eventually keep asking for characters, then once the user is done, they'll type ‘!’ to make the loop end and move on to printing their list of chars

```
public static String isValidLetter(){
    char[] charArray;
    charArray = new char[11];
    charArray[0] ='C';
    charArray[1] ='E';
    charArray[2] ='F';
    charArray[3] ='H';
    charArray[4] ='I';
    charArray[5] ='J';
    charArray[6] ='L';
    charArray[7] ='O';
    charArray[8] ='P';
    charArray[9] ='S';
    charArray[10] ='T';
    charArray[11] ='U';

    String input;
    char letter;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a single character: ");
    input=kb.nextLine();
    letter = input.charAt(0);
```

Comment: Can you state exactly what your question is? You are only showing us half of the code. Are you asking about the input loop or about the search?

Comment: Is the point of your assignment to write a search algorithm, or are you looking for an easier way to search a data structure, something like ArrayList.contains()? I'm thinking ArrayList is the way to go here, since you state that the code should keep asking for input until the termination character is entered, suggesting an open ended situation. Use arrays when you know in advance the precise size of your input and ArrayList otherwise.

Comment: You can't do this with scanner, the delimiter on console is the ENTER and not the !

Comment: Ok, so this is the whole code for the method. User will type "C", Enter, "P", Enter, "!". The program will check for validity (yes c and p are there, ! means stop), then will send "c" and "p" to another method that will print those letters out of asterisks. I want to get to the checking for validity. If the user types in "a", "b", "d", I'll have it say "try again".

Comment: @henriquedsg89 `!` should not act as the delimiter. It is the exit condition for the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the strings from console.. type "a", enter, "b", enter, "!", enter

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scann = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> letterWords = new LinkedList<String>();
        String str = null;
        while (!"!".equals(str)) {
            str = scann.next();
            letterWords.add(str);
        }
        for (String word : letterWords) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        scann.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a "collection" of valid characters, then you also could use a `String` instead of an array. It would be much easier to search in it and it avoids errors like in your example (you've initialized your array with size of `11`, but you're inserting `12` elements):

```
public static boolean isValidLetter(final char character) {
    final String validCharacters = "CEFHIJLOPSTU";
    return validCharacters.contains(String.valueOf(character));
}
```

This method expects a single `char` and returns `true` if it is valid, `false` otherwise. Please mind, that this check is `case sensitive`.

You could use that method like this:

```
final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;
while (!(input = scan.nextLine()).equals("!")) {
    if (!input.isEmpty() && isValidLetter(input.charAt(0))) {
        // ... store valid input
        System.out.println("valid");
    }
}
```

This loop requests user input until he enters `!`. I've omitted the storing part. It is up to you to do this last part.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your isValidLetter method to return boolean.
Modify your isValidLetter method to get a char as a parameter.
In isValidLetter, try to find a letter by using a helper function, something like:

```
static boolean contains(char c, char[] array) {
    for (char x : array) {
        if (x == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Somewhere in your code where you need the input (or in main for testing), ask for user input (as you already did in isValidLetter). Perform a loop, asking for input, until it is right, or until it is your ending character.

I am not posting the complete solution code on purpose, as it is better for you to play with the code and learn. I only gave directions on how to try; of course it is not the only way, but it fits with what you've already started.